# Passing reference betwen two union sub queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

in MS sql server, i have a query like this

```
select start_date, end_date, role, userId from T1
union 
select start_date, end_date,role, userId from T2
where 
T2.userId = T1.userId
```

currently I am getting incorrect syntax error on the last line

Comment: what are you tring to do here ??

Comment: Are you thinking of a join?

Comment: union 2 subqueries, seems the lower query can't reference the tables in the up query

Comment: Why do you have two such similar tables?

Comment: Of course you can't reference the other select's columns. How would that work?!?

Comment: Add some sample table data for t1 and t2, and the exected result!

Comment: thanks jarlh with your help, I just realised my query doesn't work! and by the way what is 'exected'?

Comment: @JunchenLiu when a commenter asks you for "expected result", they are asking you to give an example of the results you want to get from your query.   And don't describe it in English.   Post it in tabular format, the way you would see it in the result pane in SSMS if your query ran successfully.   It's especially valid in this case, because I can't imagine what you're trying to do with your query.   Probably this is an XY problem.  There's no logical reason to want to do what it appears you are trying to do.

Comment: Excuse my spelling error, of course I meant expected.

Comment: sql query is pretty self-explanatory ---Joe Celko

Comment: @jarlh sorry for not smart enough to understand your "of course" meant words, just as you couldn't understand the question clearly shows I wanted to reference T1 from the lower subquery, and I was just wondering is there other ways to achieve that..

Comment: If you add sample table data, and the expected result we will be able to assist. But as it is now, people are just guessing what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: All this talk of 'upper and lower query' makes me think you might be wanting a Common Table Expression (which itself is another, usually more logical, way to express a subquery). Perhaps you could investigate that option.

Comment: @jarlh sorry for being a bit cynical, and thanks for trying to help. I will add more details later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach will not work for you.  [UNION and UNION ALL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) combines one or more resultsets.

Example:

```
Table 1
UserId
1
2

Table 2
UserId
2
3
```

Using UNION the results would be deduplicated and combined:

```
Result
UserId
1
2
3
```

UNION ALL would return:

```
Result
UserId
1
2
2
3
```

Because the contents of T1.UserId and T2.UserId are now in the same column you cannot search for matches.  Instead you probably want a [JOIN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
SELECT
    T1.UserId
    T2.UserId
FROM
    T1 
        INNER JOIN T2 ON T2.UserId = T1.UserId
;
```

This will return:

```
UserId   UserId
2        2
```

Comment: While everything you said is correct, right now you're just guessing at what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: I guess join doesn't bring the dataset from the lower subquery in to the final result, my intention is to eliminate the result from the lower query by referencing tables from the upper query. now I learnt it's not possible, I guess it's a good thing to know

Comment: @TabAlleman was right, I shouldn't have posted an answer until we clearly understood your needs.  If you can show what you have (sample records for each table) and what you need (mockup of expected result, based on the samples provided) it will help your future questions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are attempting, one way to do it is like this:

```
SELECT {Columns}
FROM Table1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Id=Table1.Id)
UNION 
SELECT {Columns}
FROM Table2
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.Id=Table2.Id)
```

The result of this would be a UNION of the two queries where only IDs that exist in both tables would be returned.

Comment: yes this would work, sorry less than 150 rep, can't upvode. have to say both subqueries looks identical, and seems a bit of duplicate and waste space, which is what I am trying to avoid in the 1st place. after all maybe I am trying to achieve things arn't logical in sql